# Is there a better way to check if a series of inputs match a certain stop condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input, exit, stop-words

**(Python 3.7)**

I have a similar program to what's included below. I was just trying to figure out if there is a better way to check if any user input matches an "end" condition, I do need to save each input separately.

```py
while True:
    fname = input("Enter Customer first name: ")
    if fname == "end":
        break
    
    lname = input("Enter Customer last name: ")
    if lname == "end":
        break

    email = input("Enter Customer email: ")
    if email == "end":
        break

    num = input("Enter Customer id: ")
    if num == "end":
        break
    elif not num.isdigit():
        num = -1
    # not worried about error here
    num = int(num)

    print(fname, lname, email, num)
print("User has ended program")
```

I'm not worried about errors at this stage just trying to brainstorm here about the cleanest implementation. I will have a lot of inputs so I'm hoping I won't have to include the same if statement over and over again for each individual input.

Comment: Why let the user enter a partial record at all?

Comment: @DavisHerring in my case I just need to be able to cancel the input procedure and return to an outer commands selection page. The above function will be used to search inside an already filled database so the completeness of the record doesn't really matter to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a good opportunity to create a user exception:

```
class UserExit(BaseException):
    pass

def get_input(prompt):
    response = input(prompt)
    if response=="end":
        raise UserExit("User Exit.")
    return response

try:
    while True:
        fname = get_input("Enter Customer first name: ")
        lname = get_input("Enter Customer last name: ")
        email = get_input("Enter Customer email: ")
        num = get_input("Enter Customer id:")
        if not num.isdigit():
            num = -1
        else:
            num = int(num)
        print (fname,lname,email,num)

except UserExit as e:
    print ("User ended program.")
```

Comment: Fantastic. I was wondering if a try except situation would work in my case but didn't know the specifics of raising a custom exception, thank you.

Comment: Ooops, I've not seen your answer and I've posted a very similar one. I feel the obligation to upvote yours while retracting mine…

Comment: @gboffi Very honorable!  Thank you.